# Murder or Accident?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

Star Trek Discovery Main character slams into a Klingon on the outside of the Klingon Space Relic/Shrine and somehow made him stab himself with his own batleth. this seems like a accidental kill more then an outright kill. So wouldn't this technically be an accident? Also didn't the Klingon Clearly Attack her first?

Comment: I haven't seen *Discovery*, but from your description, my suspicion is that it was a [false flag attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag) to justify the war by making it look like the other side started it first.

Answer (score 4):

There's no (in-universe) evidence the Torchbearer attacked Burnham first, as her suit's flight recorder was corrupted by the radiation / dampening field.

Additionally, it is clear this particular Klingon house is already in the final stages of attempting to unite the other houses around a prophecy / call to action and will attack the Federation. The accidental / self-defense killing of the Torchbearer is not what pushed this conflict to the brink. It was going to happen anyway.